# Multiple Tags / expected tokens issue in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am having an issue in pom.xml file. Does anyone know what am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M3</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>${junit.version}.0-M3</junit.vintage.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M3</junit.platform.version>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>6.0.5</mysql.connector.version>
        <jooq.verson>3.9.1</jooq.verson>
    </properties>

    <plugin>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
       <configuration>
       <include>
       <include>**/Test*.java</include>
           <include>**/*Test.java</include>
           <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
           <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
           <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
       </include>
       </configuration>

       <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
           <version>LATEST</version>
       </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
               <version>LATEST</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
               <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.liquidbase</groupId>
<artifactId>liduidbase</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
</plugin>

<configuration>

<driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
<url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33306/monster_app?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true</url>
<username>monster_user</username>
<password>monster_password</password>
<changeLogFile>src/main/java/com/example/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
<promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
</executions>
        </plugin>
<groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
<artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
<configuration>
<jdbc>
<driver>com.mysqk.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33306/monster_app?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true</url>
    <username>monster_user</username>
    <password>monster_password</password>
</jdbc>
<generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>
    <database>
    <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
   <inputSchema>monster_app</inputSchema>
    <includes>.*</includes>
    </database>

    <target>

     <packageName>com.example.Generated</packageName>
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </target>
</generator>
</configuration>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
 <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
 <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
 <snapshots>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
 </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
 <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
 <version>${cucumber.version</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.11</version>
 <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.5</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
 <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
<version>${jooq.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>org.jooq</artifactId>
    <groupId>jooq-codegen</groupId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

I can't figure out what am doing wrong. the first 3 lines give me multiple tags error and last line gives me unexpected token.

This code has been tried on another persons machine and it seems to be working fine. 
I dont think I have anything weird in there but it still not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

You're just missing the `project` tag name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear multiple structure issues in your pom.xml, let me list a couple of them below :

1. The second line should have the project as the tag, like this :

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
2. should reside inside a  tag, and all the  tags should 
   then reside inside the  tag.
3. tag should reside inside a particular  tag.

My recommendation is if you are using an IDE such as Eclipse, then type Ctrl + Space to show the suggestions for each tag. This will help you move the tags to its relevant section. Also, you should keep all the dependencies above the  section.